# Prevent onfocus() to clear date in textbox

Tags: javascript, date, textbox, onfocus

I would need to allow the date that I keyed in to stay in the text box even when I click on the text box or datepicker to change the date.
Here's an example from this website to show what I want >>>>> http://www.flyscoot.com/index.php/en/

See, after I key in the departure date, and after that when I click on the text box or datepicker, the previous date that I entered is still shown on the text box.

I think the problem lies with the calendar tag `onfocus` line. Say if I remove `onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');">` yes the date stay put in the textbox, but it doesn't allow me to key in the date **manually** anymore.

What should I add in to my code to allow this function to work?

Javascript:

```
function parseDate(s) {

    //including leap year:
      var reg = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g; 


    if (!reg.test(s)) {
        return "Invalid Date";
    }
    var dateParts = s.split("/");

    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

    var dateStrParts = date.toString().split(" ");

    return (date.getDate() + ", " + dateStrParts[1] + " " + dateStrParts[3]);
}
```

Calendar Tag:

```
<p:calendar 
value="#{pc_Rpt2202.asat_date}"
id="rp2202_input_as_at" 
styleClass="calendar" 
maxlength="10"
pattern="dd MMM yyyy"
onchange="$(this).val(parseDate($(this).val()))"
onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');"
>
<p:watermark for="rp2202_input_as_at" value="dd/MMM/yyyy" />
```

Comment: could you please include which jQuery plugins you are using so that we can set up a jsfiddle to debug it?

Comment: @Markasoftware Datepicker? Am currently using primefaces